# Bad window path name ".snd"

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Can someone please help me with this issue? Also please kindly explain me the instructions step to step cause I have less experience and understanding regarding Programming things. Thanks again

[image: photo]

Comment: welcome to SO! Provide some code for your question: what you tried, errors, etc See also  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It seems like the window was not created or got destroyed. In anycase, it might be better to contact the person who wrote the code as it seems to be quite a big file.

Comment: If you follow the trace back in the error message from the bottom to the top, you will find the line of code that is causing the error. We would need to see the code in that neighborhood to have any chance of helping you.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Mango and Jerry. Unfortunately I still can't find the original code of the app, I think I'm gonna delete the installation of the app first and reinstall the new one. Is is okay?

Answer (score 1):

About all we can tell from that message is that the `.snd` widget (“widget” is the name for a window or control component in the Tk toolkit, which is the primary GUI library for Tcl) was not existing at the point where that `pack configure` command was called. Except we've got a bit more context from the stack trace: it's in a procedure called `CreateWidgets` that was called from another procedure called `CreateGUI` so it's almost certainly doing widget creation and setup (`pack configure` is a reasonable setup action).

Given that, the problem is probably either that the code is asking to work with a widget that it hasn't created yet (funny how that won't work!) or has a typo which is making it ask to use the name of something that will never exist, or something has caused the widget to be deleted earlier than expected. Without seeing the code it's hard to be sure which. A typo is fairly possible, as is failing to construct a compound widget name correctly (which is also a kind of typo I guess) but putting the manipulation code before the creation code is definitely a possibility. An early delete is less likely *in general* but can't be discounted.

As the code is apparently well over a thousand lines long, I don't think it'll be easy to find volunteers to look through it.

Comment: Thanks Fellows. Definitely the typo thing that has caused all of it. Your explanation is very clear thanks but Programming is still a big task for me.

Comment: Thanks Fellows. Definitely the typo thing that has caused all of it. Your explanation is very clear thanks but Programming is still a big task for me.